# How does a liquid crystal on Silicon affect the phase of incident light?

Tags: optics, visible-light, semiconductor-physics, crystals

When a polarized light beam is directed to a phase-only LCoS system how is the phase modulated ? What is the physical effect behind ?
Does voltage modulation has an impact on birefringence ?

Comment: The Widipedia article is rather short on info but appears to have some interesting links. You might start with them.

Comment: Thank you. In my understanding the E field components become delayed differently. Due the apearing phasedifference between the two components the polarization of the beam turns. An additional analyzer helps to modulate the intensity. Can one only achieve phase only modulation (w/o modulating the polarization) if one uses a beam with only one polarization component ?